# log4net AdoNetAppender stops logging - Can't find type - Custom logger

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm hoping someone can give me some insight into why when using log4net's AdoNetAppender I'll get logs for a day, maybe two, and then they just stop.  I have reconnectOnError set to true, but still no logs. My bufferSize is also set to 1, so if I write a log, I should see it instantly, which I do when the application is started. I have two log tables, one for tracking information, and one for normal logs.  The normal log4net log is unmodified and I believe always logs, the other is a custom log I use to track web service requests. Both logs work as expected after startup.

A day latter, sometimes more, sometimes less, I go back to check the logs and the application work, but nothing is log to the custom logger.

**Update!! After letting everything sit overnight, I find this in the error logs:**

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find type [Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern]
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type [Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern]. Tried assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a] and all loaded assemblies
at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)
log4net:ERROR Failed to create object to set param: layout
```

All the Fcn.Logging objects are in a separately built library called Common that is shared by multiple applications at Fcn.  I don't remember this issue when the objects were part of each web service, but I believe the problem started when I split them up so that I wouldn't have to drop them into each and every application that I create that needs them.

I'm initializing log4net in the Global.asax.cs with the following code:

```
private static readonly ILog log4net = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Global));
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        log4net.Info("Logging initialized");
    }
```

My web.config configuration for this is as follows:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="textWriterTraceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="E:\PseudoFileServer\Logging\wsFCNCheck\log4net.txt" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="TestLog2.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%p] [%c:%L] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="AdoLog4NetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserName;Password=UserPass" />
    <reconnectOnError>true</reconnectOnError>
    <commandText value="[WS].[WebServiceLogOnly_Insert]" />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <appender name="AdoNetTrackingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UserName;Password=UserPass" />
    <reconnectOnError>true</reconnectOnError>
    <commandText value="[WS].[WebServiceTracking_Insert]" />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@WebServiceRequestTypeKey" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{webservicerequesttypekey}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@CallerSource" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="5" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{callersource}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@UserID" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{userid}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Request" />
      <dbType value="Xml" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{request}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ResponseTypeKey" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{responsetypekey}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@WebServiceResponseMessageKey" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{webserviceresponsemessagekey}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Response" />
      <dbType value="Xml" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{response}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@StartTime" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{starttime}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@EndTime" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{endtime}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@StoredProcedureCallTimeInMS" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{storedprocedurecalltimeinms}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@MSGeocode" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{msgeocode}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@GeocodeFailOverUsed" />
      <dbType value="Boolean" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{geocodefailoverused}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@GeocodeRequest" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{geocoderequest}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@GeocodeResponse" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{geocoderesponse}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="WARNING" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoLog4NetAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger additivity="false" name="Tracking">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetTrackingAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

I changed the reconnect tag to look like this:

```
<reconnectOnError value="true" /> <!-- I believe this is the correct syntax -->
<reconnectOnError>true</reconnectOnError> <!-- This I believe is incorrect syntax -->
```

Can someone confirm which is the correct syntax?

**At this point I also changed the custom loggers to specify which assembly they are in.  This might be the only problem, but I'm getting an additional error at this point.  I'll detail the configuration change and then the new error.**

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="TestLog2.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <param name="ImmediateFlush" value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%p] [%c:%L] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log-file.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="AdoLog4NetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Username;Password=Password" />
    <reconnectOnError value="true" />
    <commandText value="[WS].[WebServiceLogOnly_Insert]" />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <appender name="AdoNetTrackingAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Username;Password=Password" />
    <reconnectOnError value="true" />
    <commandText value="[WS].[WebServiceTracking_Insert]" />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@WebServiceRequestTypeKey" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{webservicerequesttypekey}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@CallerSource" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="5" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{callersource}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@UserID" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{userid}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Request" />
      <dbType value="Xml" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{request}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@ResponseTypeKey" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{responsetypekey}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@WebServiceResponseMessageKey" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{webserviceresponsemessagekey}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@Response" />
      <dbType value="Xml" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{response}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@StartTime" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{starttime}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@EndTime" />
      <dbType value="DateTime2" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{endtime}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@StoredProcedureCallTimeInMS" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{storedprocedurecalltimeinms}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@MSGeocode" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{msgeocode}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@GeocodeFailOverUsed" />
      <dbType value="Boolean" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{geocodefailoverused}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@GeocodeRequest" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{geocoderequest}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@GeocodeResponse" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="-1" />
      <layout type="Fcn.Logging.TrackingLayoutPattern, Common">
        <conversionPattern value="%Tracking{geocoderesponse}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="WARNING" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoLog4NetAppender" />
  </root>
  <logger additivity="false" name="Tracking">
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetTrackingAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

Will the , Common for the assembly name address the Can't find type error?

And the new error is the following:

```
    log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName, Boolean shouldReconnect)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.System.Data.IDbConnection.BeginTransaction()
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
ClientConnectionId:6f780eae-73cd-4c2d-bc26-545b3234f161
Error Number:10053,State:0,Class:20
```

I'm about to install the updated config section on an internal company server instead of testing locally.  I'm wondering if the latest error is due to the VPN being recycled every 12 hours.  From googling the error I'm also worried that the connection was closed by SQL server due to inactivity.  If this is the case I would suspect the reconnect on error tag set to true to address this.  Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Which application method are you initializing logging in?

Comment: @user2197446 were you able to fix the issue / track it down?

Comment: The main problem is here:

`<parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime**2**" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>`

Please use `DateTime` instead of `DateTime2`.